# Copy to clipboard is copying value with two newlines

Tags: reactjs

I have a code that copy the text value of a paragraph element in React to the clipboard.

The code is working (copying the value to the clipboard) but is it copying the value plus two newlines into the clipboard.

For example if I want to copy the value '2345678' it will copy:

```
'2345678



'
```

```
import './CopyClipboard.css';

class CopyClipboard extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.textContent = null;
        this.state = {
            copied: false
        };
    }

    copyToClipboard = async e => {
        window.getSelection().removeAllRanges();
        var range = document.createRange();
        range.selectNode(this.textContent);
        window.getSelection().addRange(range);
        document.execCommand("copy");
        window.getSelection().removeAllRanges();
        this.setState({ copied: true });
    };

    initRef = c => (this.textContent = c);

    render() {
        const { copied } = this.state;
        return (
            <div className="positioning">
                <p onMouseLeave={() => this.setState({ copied: false })} onClick={this.copyToClipboard} ref={this.initRef}>
                    {this.props.value}
                </p>
                {copied === false ? <p className="success">Copy to Clipboard</p> : <p className="success">Copied!!!</p>}
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default CopyClipboard;
```

maybe someone can understand what am I doing wrong here ?

Thanks!

so I managed to get it working using @ChrisSandvik solution to use clipboard-polyfill

the code:

```
import React from 'react';
import * as clipboard from "clipboard-polyfill";
import './CopyClipboard.css';

class CopyClipboard extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            copied: false
        };
    }

    copyText = e => {
        clipboard.writeText(this.props.value);
        this.setState({ copied: true });
    };

    render() {
        const { copied } = this.state;
        return (
            <div className="positioning">
                <p onMouseLeave={() => this.setState({ copied: false })} onClick={this.copyText} ref={this.initRef}>
                    {this.props.value}
                </p>
                {copied === false ? <p className="success">Copy to Clipboard</p> : <p className="success">Copied!!!</p>}
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default CopyClipboard;
```

EDIT 2:

I found the problem, the value passed was ok, but `<p></p>` elements have default css that is effecting the value that you will get when you retrieve it.
you can fix it by either using `<span>` or overriding the `<p>` default css

Comment: Did you check range have valid values? Moreover, did you try using similar method `selectNodeContents` ?

Comment: Is `textContent` a JSX element or just a string

Comment: @ChrisSandvik is the `ref` for `p`

Answer (score 2):

I believe Venecovsky might be on the right track with the line breaks.  However, another solution that I tend to lean towards when dealing with clipboard stuff in React is to use the [clipboard-polyfil](https://www.npmjs.com/package/clipboard-polyfill) package.

This would reduce your code down to:

```js
copyToClipboard = async e => {
    clipboard.writeText(this.props.value);
};
```

And is also guaranteed to work better cross browser and cross device.

You also wouldn't have to deal with refs!

**EDIT:**

I made a working and very simple demo you can check out here: https://codesandbox.io/s/strange-darkness-wzrjz

```js
const ClipboardThing = props => {
  const copyText = e => {
    clipboard.writeText(props.value);
    changeButtonText(e.target, "Copied!");
  };

  const changeButtonText = (button, text) => {
    const original = button.textContent;
    button.textContent = text;
    setTimeout(() => {
      button.textContent = original;
    }, 1200);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <p>{props.value}</p>
      <button onClick={copyText}>Copy Text</button>
    </div>
  );
};

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <ClipboardThing value="test text" />
    </div>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/clipboard-polyfill/2.8.1/clipboard-polyfill.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: Hi Man, Thanks. I managed to get it working using clipboard-polyfill. but I dont understand why it was not working before ? :\

Comment: My guess is that it was copying extra newline characters from the way the values were laid out in the jsx.  As in, putting the value on a new line in your p tag instead of keeping it all on one line would keep the extra line return when selecting the range, even if it didn't visually change anything.

Comment: If that wasn't the specific reason then I'm not sure exactly.  All I know is that ranges can be weird sometimes.

Answer (score 0):

## Edit:

Use `span` instead of `p`.

```
<span onMouseLeave={() => this.setState({ copied: false })} onClick={this.copyToClipboard} ref={this.initRef}>{this.props.value}</span >
```

## Old:

Try adding it in one line only, without indenting the code (remove `enter` and `spaces` of the code).

```
<p onMouseLeave={() => this.setState({ copied: false })} onClick={this.copyToClipboard} ref={this.initRef}>{this.props.value}</p>
```

One thing you can check is `this.props.value.length`, maybe the value is already comming with two extra line.

OR

One thing you can do is use `.trim` to remove the extra line breaks.

Comment: tried all three ideas... it didn't work. I managed to get it working with @ChrisSandvik idea using clipboard-polyfill.
still I just dont get what was wrong with the original code :\

Comment: @user3657538 have you checked `this.props.value.length` ? what does it appears?

Comment: @Vencovsky1 yes I checked, the length was correct. I even tried to trim it... it didnt work...

Comment: @user3657538 the only reason that it would give 2 extra lines is that if the lines comes from the code indentation, but if it isn't that, not sure why it happens

Comment: @ Vencovsky I found the problem, the value passed was ok, but ```<p></p>``` elements have default css that is effecting the value that you will get when you retrieve it.
you can fix it by either using ```<span>``` or overriding the ```<p>``` default css

Comment: @user3657538 Nice! I edited my answer just in case someone comes back in this question.